# Read values in a CSV file into two dimensional array

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV file with multiple rows and columns. I want to read the values into a two dimensional array so I can access each single value. There is a thread about how to read CSV files into an array which is
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614526/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-a-data-array)

When I try that code it still reads each row as one item into a list, which then I can't separate. Could you help with that?

The code I tried is this:

```
with open("filename.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
    data = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
    print(data)
```

The csv file's format is like this:

```
value1,value2,value3,value4

value5,value6,value7,value8
```

And the array that I get should be:

```
[[value1, value2, value3, value4]

[value5, value6, value7, value8]]
```

So when I say `print(data[0,0])` it will print `value1`

Comment: _which then I can't separate_ can you show some sample data and expected output ?

Comment: What about using `pandas`? You can find plenty of documentation online where to start and how get the access to every item inside the file.

Comment: Is the data homogeneous (e.g. all numbers)?

Comment: I have edited the question to explain @stud3nt

Comment: yes they are all numbers. One column is timestamps tho. @norok2

Comment: Your code works fine: outputs `[['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['2', '3', '4', '5'], ['3', '4', '5', '6'], ['4', '5', '6', '7']]` for a similar file

Comment: you're not providing enough information. what do you actually get as output? what does your input actually look like?

Comment: Your code is working fine as others have said. To access the first element in first row you should use `data[0][0]` and not `data[0,0]`.

Comment: yes it works now. I think the only problem was how I tried to print the values. Thanks guys! @stud3nt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this i hope it will help

```
 datafile = open('filename.csv', 'r')
 datareader = csv.reader(datafile, delimiter=';')
 data = []
 for row in datareader:
     data.append(row)    
 print (data[1:4])
```