# What is the 'python version' of array[i]?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am learning Python and trying to compare the elements of multiple arrays/lists at a time, my arrays are Numpy arrays (I guess?) as I did [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67302172/13061992) to create them and the answer mentions the output as a numpy array

I have 3 arrays of length 40 in total and what I want to do is iterate through them and check if elements at the same index are equal, in a programming language such as Java I can easily do this using something like:

```
for (int i=0;i<40; i++)
   if(array1[i]==array2[i]==array3[i] 
     //do whatever
```

however I am having trouble doing this as tutorials on iterating through the array will be something like this:

```
for x in arr:
  \\do work
```

with no reference to an index, any help would be appreciated

UPDATE: for more clarification, I used the linked answer to import a csv file with strings to a numpy array, so my array elements are strings

here is what print(array) outputs, I have 3 of those

[image]

Comment: `for i, x in enumerate(arr):` is a good way to get the index and item. If you just need the index `for i in range(len(arr)):`, but that is considered "unpythnic" if you just want to iterate one `list` (that's the real name for what you call "array").

Comment: But much better implementation will be `for ar1element, ar2element, ar3element in zip(array1, array2, array3)`

Comment: What happened when you tried putting `how does a for loop work in python` into a search engine? Or looking for and following any kind of tutorial? Or anything remotely like that? And if you don't understand how to do something as basic as this, why are you trying to use as complex of a library as Numpy?

Comment: It seems you know the word `iterate`, and that you're aware that what you want to do is iterate through Numpy arrays in parallel. So maybe you could try a more tailored search on that basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
for x,y,z in zip(array1,array2,array3):
    if(x==y and x==z):
        #Do Something
```

Comment: I got the following : "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()" the arrays have strings as elements if that matters

Comment: Please give a better discription of what you expect `array1`, `array2` and `array3` to be.

Comment: check the post update for more clarification

Comment: Then change the `if` statement to: `if(np.array_equal(x,y) and np.array_equal(x,z)):`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index by enumerating the list.

```
for idx, val in enumerate(arr):
    print(idx, val)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `zip()` function.

```
num1 = [1, 2, 3]
num2 = [3, 4, 35]
num3 = [21, 24, 43]

for n1, n2, n3 in zip(num1, num2, num3):
  print(n1, n2, n3)
```

Output:

```
1 3 21
2 4 24
3 35 43
```

Comment: this method did not work as I said in another comment, I got the following : "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()" the arrays have strings as elements if that matters

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np    
where_equal = np.where(np.logical_and(array1==array2, array2==array3))
for i,j in zip(*where_equal):
    #do stuff... for example
    print(array1[i,j])
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

zip(*where_equal) unpacks the tuple of indices returned by np.where and then zips into an iterable.